# Javascript override of jQuery (or any other object's) method

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects, dom-events

In this ***[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Akqur/8/)***, the author writes a test for some custom knockout binding. As part of the test, it seems that he/she extends jQuery.

Is my understanding of line `30. 
$.fn.on = function(event, callback) {` that it overrides, without subsequent cleanup  anything that jQuery might have defined as `on` on its prototype? Same question for line 36 and the fadeOut.

Here's the relevant snippets and you can check the fiddle to look for cleanup:

```
30. $.fn.on = function(event, callback) {
31.   ...
...
36. $.fn.fadeOut = function(speed, callback) {
37.   ...
```

I am asking in general, not directly related to jquery (i.e. jquery may or may not have anything for `on` and `fadeOut`.) I am considering embedding a similar test into production code and I don't want my test altering jQuery or whatever "real" object my test may be touching that way. On that note, it seems that even if there was cleanup, some other event-driven (async) calls may stumble on the changed implementations - am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't only override anything defined in the prototype, it actually replaces it. The `$.fn` property is a copy of the prototype for the jQuery object, so `$.fn` is the actual prototype, i.e. `$.fn === jQuery.prototype`.

You are correct that you can't isolate such a change to your own calls to the object, it would also affect any other code calling the object as long as your change was in effect.

However, as jQuery is strictly single threaded, you could change the prototype, use the object and then change the prototype back, and no other code could be affected. As long as you have code running without a break, there are no events handled.

Comment: Thanks - great answer. Would an approach where I first construct my new "test" elements and then only alter their own prototypes work better/be more isolated?

Comment: @G.Stoynev: If you mean the prototype of jQuery objects, then there is only one single prototype for all instances (which goes for all object types by the way), so that won't be more isolated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it overrides jQuery's prototype. It doesn't extend anything, `$.fn` is an alias for jQuery's prototype ([line 54 of core.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L54) is `jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {...}`) so overwriting `$.fn.on` blows away jQuery.

Watch the log here: http://jsfiddle.net/LzGmJ/